# How do i pass array object in action method?

Tags: arrays, json, jqgrid

I'm getting error in the method `$.toJSON(batch)` that object does not support this property or method. How can i pass batch array using `$.toJASON(batch)` method?

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '@Url.Action("BatchUpdate", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            //data: '{viewModelsBatch: '+batch+'}',
            data: $.toJSON(batch),
            success: function(result) {
              //...
              $('#jqgProducts').trigger('reloadGrid');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Paul Grime that the usage of `JSON.stringify` from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) is better as `toJSON` jQuery plugin. The reason is that `JSON.stringify` is **native** implemented in the most web browsers. You should include `json2.js` only to be sure that if the web browser do have no support of `JSON.stringify` the implementation in JavaScript will be used. The typical jQuery plugin is on the other side pure JavaScript code. So the serialization will be *slowly*. Moreover the author of [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) is Douglas Crockford - the author of JSON standard and very famous specialist in JavaScript language. So his implementation of JSON serialization in JavaScript is really the best.

Your main question was another: why `data: $.toJSON(batch)` or `data: JSON.stringify(batch)` will not work in your code. The problem is not jqGrid problem, but pure server side problem. You don't wrote what technology you use on the server side. The code looks like ASP.NET MVC code, but it's unclear *which version of ASP.NET MVC you use*. If you use version 3.0 it should work automatically, but in case of 2.0 version you need register custom `JsonValueProviderFactory` (see [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)).

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.0.0 of mvc, i've included json2.js file but still getting same error. :(

Comment: @farhan: In any way it's pure ASP.MVC problem. So you should include at least the prototype of `BatchUpdate` action which you use and the test `batch` which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `toJSON` function is, so I'd recommend reading this answer.

[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)